# Column value not in index in padas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am calculating a new column in dataframe using a regular expression with [named capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) as follows:

```
(df["Address Column"]
.str.extract("(?P<Address>.*\d+[\w+?|\s]\s?\w+\s+\w+),?\s(?P<Suburb>.*$)")
.apply(lambda x: x.str.title()))
```

However, I am getting a `KeyError` when calling new column "Suburb"

```
KeyError: "['Suburb'] not in index"
```

Sample data:

```
**Address column**
4a Mcarthurs Road, Altona north
1 Neal court, Altona North 
4 Vermilion Drive, Greenvale
Lot 307 Bonds Lane, Greenvale
430 Blackshaws rd, Altona North 
159 Bonds lane, Greenvale
```

Desired output:

```
Address                   Suburb
4a Mcarthurs Road        Altona North
1 Neal court              Altona North
4 Vermilion Drive          Greenvale
Lot 307 Bonds Lane         Greenvale
430 Blackshaws rd         Altona North
159 Bonds lane              Greenvale
```

Not sure why I am getting this!

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe (for example the head of your pd.Series)

Comment: Hello, updated my question with sample data

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with pandas v1.2.4. Which version are you working with?

Comment: Same here with pandas 1.2.3 (use pd.__version__ in python to check your version)

Comment: mine is pandas 1.2.4

Comment: Btw, always use rawstrings for regex patterns (ie r"(?P<Address>..." )

Comment: just updated this str.extract(r"(?P<Address>.."). but still not working

Comment: For me, `s.str.extract(r).apply(lambda x: x.str.title())` yields the desired output, where `r` contains the regular expression, and `s` is the series with the sample data. I tested with Python3.8 and pandas 1.2.4 in a IPython shell session. It can even handle missing entries.

Comment: +1 for showing the use of named capture groups, by the way. I didn't know that pandas can handle those naturally.

Comment: Are you the KeyError is triggered by the extract method ? Not somewhere after that while affecting the results ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't assign the result of your regexp query to the original `df`.

The following works for me:

```py
r = r"(?P<Address>.*\d+[\w+?|\s]\s?\w+\s+\w+),?\s(?P<Suburb>.*$)"
ret = df["Address Column"].str.extract(r).apply(lambda x: x.str.title())
df = pd.concat([df, ret], axis=1)
df["Suburb"]
```

---

For completeness, this is how I initialized `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["4a Mcarthurs Road, Altona north",
               "1 Neal court, Altona North",
               "4 Vermilion Drive, Greenvale",
               "Lot 307 Bonds Lane, Greenvale",
               "430 Blackshaws rd, Altona North",
               "159 Bonds lane, Greenvale"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Address Column": s})
```

The above code adds the new columns `Address` and `Suburb` to `df`:

```text
                 Address Column             Address        Suburb
4a Mcarthurs Road, Altona north   4A Mcarthurs Road  Altona North
     1 Neal court, Altona North        1 Neal Court  Altona North
   4 Vermilion Drive, Greenvale   4 Vermilion Drive     Greenvale
  Lot 307 Bonds Lane, Greenvale  Lot 307 Bonds Lane     Greenvale
430 Blackshaws rd, Altona North   430 Blackshaws Rd  Altona North
      159 Bonds lane, Greenvale      159 Bonds Lane     Greenvale
```

Comment: Hi, I have ~150 row values with in "address column". Should I ingest all row values in pd.series? Apart from this, i might have different address tomorrow and day after. It will be a tedious work to ingest with new values in series.  Not just this, there are other columns(38) which is required to be aligned with my current df. How can I do it in more simplistic manner?

Comment: @adey27 The initialization of the df is just for demo purposes! (I didn't have your data frame available, so I had to construct one myself.) You of course skip this part and operate directly with your df.

Comment: @adey27 Does the line `ret = ...` work for you? Have you looked at the result?

Comment: yes i did that suggestions. but getting NaN's in Suburb column outputs

Comment: Yay, the KeyError is gone! See it from the bright side :)

Comment: @adey Are you getting only NaNs, or some NaNs? It could be that the regular expression does not work well. Try my dummy-dataframe from above, does it work? If yes, try to understand what the differences are to your data frame. Debugging is not something I can do for you if you unless you share the details of your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Most of them are NaNs. Even suburb names are not appearing correctly. It did separate suburb value from the original column. But in new column  output data is nor correct. My requirement is to create a new column with Suburb values. thats all. Just not able to do it.

Comment: @adey27 Alright, I see. Solving your KeyError problem isn't enough. Does the output of the sample df I used above correspond to what you expect? If not, you need to be more precise. With "it's just not working" I really can't help any further.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I expect. I can understand @normanius.. Really appreciate your help.